# Find tan(C/2) in The triangle ABC .

Tags: trigonometry

$ABC$ is a triangle.

$\tan\frac{A}{2}  = 0.5$

$\tan\frac{B}{2}  =\frac{1}{3}$.

Find $\tan\frac{C}{2}$.

I tried to find it :

when $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$

So $\frac{A}{2} + \frac{B}{2} + \frac{C}{2} = 90^{\circ}$.

How can I complete on these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following identity is very useful.
$$\tan\frac{A}{2}\tan\frac{B}{2}+\tan\frac{A}{2}\tan\frac{C}{2}+\tan\frac{B}{2}\tan\frac{C}{2}=1$$
From here $C=90^{\circ}$

We can get this result by geometric way.

Let $P(0,0)$,$Q(2,1)$ and $R(3,-1)$. Draw it!

Hence $PQ=QR$, $\measuredangle Q=90^{\circ}$ and from here $$\arctan{\frac{1}{2}}+\arctan{\frac{1}{3}}=\measuredangle Q=45^{\circ},$$
which says that our $\frac{C}{2}=45^{\circ}$ and we are done!

Comment: True ✔️ Thank you @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @Hamzeh K. Yacoub I added another solution. See please.

Answer (score 1):

∴ $\dfrac C2 = 90^0 –(\dfrac A2 + \dfrac B2)$

Then, $\tan (\dfrac {C}{2}) = \cot (\dfrac A2 + \dfrac B2) = \dfrac {1}{\tan (\dfrac A2 + \dfrac B2)} = \dfrac {1 -\tan (\dfrac A2) \tan (\dfrac B2)}{\tan (\dfrac A2) + \tan (\dfrac B2)} = ...$

Added:- It is the application of the compound angle formula $\tan (x + y) = \dfrac {\tan x + \tan y}{1 - \tan x \times \tan y}$.

Comment: I didn't understand the third step $Mick

Comment: @HamzehK.Yacoub See the last line added.

Comment: So u mean tan(A/2)+tan(B/2) in the bottom

Comment: @HamzehK.Yacoub You are right. I fixed the typo.